# The image doesn't disappear after deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the array of images coming from the data base as byte array to be displayed in their respective `div`-s. Each `div` has a delete button and a placeholder image that is displayed before and after the deletion of the database image. the `img` tags that have images put into them have id-s from 1 to 21. If there are more than one images the deletion happens with no issues both on the front-end and the back-end. The problem arises when there is only one image left. It shows that the last image is deleted on the backend but stays unchanged on the front-end, though after refresh it disappears.  I don't know why that is happening. Here is the code:

```js
function refresh() {
  var year = parseInt($("#existing_seasons_input_field").val(), 10);
  var season = $("#existing_seasons_input").val();
  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllDocsForSeason", "MaillingOrder")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {
      year: year,
      season: season
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: function(val) {
      var tempList = val.Value;
      for (var i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
        var elem = tempList[i];
        const test = elem.FileContent.Inhalt;
        const convert = arrayBufferToBase64(test);
        var container = document.getElementById(i + 1);
        container.src = "data:image/*;base64," + convert;
        container.name = String(elem.DocId);
        $("#file-" + (i + 1) + "-haeder-text").val(elem.DocHeader);
        var bodyTextDiv = $("#textContainer" + (i + 1))[0];
        var content = document.createTextNode(elem.DocDescription);
        bodyTextDiv.appendChild(content);
        if (i + 1 === tempList.length) {
          var container2 = document.getElementById(i + 2);
          container2.src = "Images/MailingOrder/download.png";
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(req, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
  });


}
```

Comment: The question does not provide enough detail to suggest a solution.  Question should include enough description and code to reproduce the problem. Yet, you can probably solve the problem yourself using the browser's inspector and debugger.

Comment: Given that your issue is with the delete function, you might like to include that function...

Comment: I suggest you look at how this can be solved without using *any* IDs (DOM IDs - you probably still need a database ID, that's a different ID (DocId)).   Specifically, when you click the delete button, use `this` and relative DOM navigation to remove the image.

Comment: @freedomn-m this is the front end delete function. the one responsible for displaying the uploaded images is almost identical without the if statement in the end.

Comment: @freedomn-m could you explain more in details what you mean with DOM IDs?

Comment: The code provided does the delete function?  It's called "refresh", calls a url `GetAllDocsForSeason`, does `createTextNode` and `.appendChild` - can't see anywhere that it removes anything.

Comment: I see quite a few questions that do something like `select docId from docs` ... append `<div id='${doc.docId}` - so this is the DB doc ID, but it's being used in the DOM (the div element) for the `div id=`.   You're not doing this as you're doing `name=docId`.    Instead you're using incremental IDs `document.getElementById(i+2)` so in your HTML (not included in the question) you'll have `<img id='3'>` for example.  The idea is to remove *that* id `<img>` and do all your actions without using .getElementById - *unique* elements are ok to have a name, eg `$("#container")`.

Comment: @freedomn-m the delete is done on the backend in c# and this is the code I am using to delete the images on the front-end, so more accurate would be to say that this is the refresh function for the front-end.

Comment: Can you provide a *complete* snippet that demonstrates the issue?  See [mcve]. As this appears to be a js issue and your backend is successfully deleting (on a GET request...), you can exclude that part and simulate the response - ie remove the ajax call.  Include relevant HTML.

Comment: On the last call, what's the value of `val` in `success: function(val) {` - maybe your backed isn't returning the correct response when there's only one image left?

Comment: @freedomn-m it decreases after the delete button is pressed